# How can I display the output of an array in Ruby Shoes?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, shoes

I've got this as my code

```
 openAll = File.open('N:\Josh\Blondie\db.txt')
 allNumbers = Array.new
 allNumbers=[]  
  openAll.each_line {|line|
    allNumbers.push line
  }

  puts allNumbers
```

and I'd like to be able to display the output of this code in a new window with Ruby Shoes, I can't seem to get it to display anything though. The contents of the file are names and phone numbers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should put some code here that tells us what you've tried, in addition to code that shows us you have data in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of outputting text to a shoes window.  Using a `puts` statement just outputs to the shell, not to the Shoes app.

```
Shoes.app :title => "GUI RAW file converter, for the CLI challenged", 
  :resizable => true do 
  background white 
  stack do 
    flow {
      background gray, :height => 30
      caption "Caption", :margin => 8, :stroke => white
      stack {
        para 'This is a fancy line I just printed to the window'
####### Here's an example line you could use to put out the array...
        allNumbers.each do |number|
          para "#{number}"
        end
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use the method Kernel#alert instead of Kernel#puts.

http://shoesrb.com/manual/Built-in.html

Comment: While `alert` will get shoes to actually do something, as compared to the `puts` statement from the OP, the alert will cause an Alert, or a pop up alert box, not content in a shoes window.